# How to create an efficient Sharepoint Microsoft Graph program?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a program that will be used to interact with Microsoft Sharepoint and perform different actions like: download files, upload files, search Sharepoint, etc..

During my research, I found that Microsoft has a "rate limit" system which limits the number of requests per period of time (see [Microsoft documentation on rate limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online)).

Here is a sample function that I have created to download a file from Sharepoint:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task<(Stream fileStream, int remainingRateLimit)> DownloadFileFromSharepoint(string clientId, string clientSecret, string tenantId, string siteId, string itemId)
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

    var authResult = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

    var driveItemUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/content";
    var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, driveItemUrl));
    var fileStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var remainingRateLimit = int.Parse(response.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-tenant")[0]);

    return (fileStream, remainingRateLimit);
}
```

The method will return a tuple containing a `Stream` object representing the downloaded file and an int value indicating the remaining rate limit for the Microsoft Graph API.

**What I want/need**

- I want to know if there is any better way or more efficient way to do this to avoid hitting the rate limit?
- If I divided the tasks between multiple applications "multiple client id's" but all in the same tenant would that help?
- If the above questions can't be done or would still hit the rate limit, any ideas to handle or minimize the impact of it "we will be doing a lot of requests to Sharepoint during peak times" and all of which are mission critical so anything would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could recommend a couple of educational videos on throttling: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywCHnt-KkDc and https://pnp.github.io/blog/microsoft-365-platform-community-call/2022-11-08/

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way. Since, you are trying to download files, upload files, and search Sharepoint. For each of these operations, the token utilization is different.

- First Get Throttling Metrics for each operation.
- Then use a Message based or event-based solution to handle those operations that consume more tokens.